# Compute shader writing to swapchain image, image layout validation error

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to write to a Swapchain image from a compute shader.

So far I have:

- Bound the Swapchain Image to a Storage Image (VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE)
- Added VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT to image usage on the Swapchain

But now I seem to be in a catch 22.

- If I define the DescriptorImageInfo to have a layout of VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR I get a validation error stating that allowed layouts are: VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL ([spec](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.261.1/mac/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkWriteDescriptorSet-descriptorType-04152))
- If I define the layout as VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, I get InvalidImageLayout stating that CommandBuffer expects the image to be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, but it is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR

Comment: "*I'm trying to write to a Swapchain image from a compute shader.*" Note that the Vulkan implementation doesn't have to allow you to do that. You need to ask the implementation if it will let you use the swapchain image as a storage image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use layout transitions.

Transition the swapchain surface into LAYOUT_GENERAL so you can write to it using the compute shader, and then use a layout transition to convert it to  VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR after the compute pass to put the image back into a presentable layout for the swapchain.

Comment: So when you say "layout transitions", do you mean ImageBarrier ?

Comment: Yes, for compute you need to use image barriers; for render passes you can use the pass setup.